# Running a defect php file cause error 500

Tags: apache-2.2, php, 500-error

When I address a PHP file, I always get an error 500. I've looked up the logs of my Apache server, and this displays that some `includes` etc. in the PHP file address files which don't exist on the server. They don't exist because I'm just testing my PHP file. But could it be achieved that the server runs the php file in every case, even when something is wrong?

Every 30 seconds an entry is made in the error_log file which says `[Sat Jun 09 17:55:07 2012] [error] [client 10.224.55.160] File does not exist: /var/www/html/index.html` ... but there IS an index.html?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server *is* running the PHP file.

Execution of the PHP is stopping when it can't load something it's including.  If you get it to ignore those errors, it'll simply error later on in execution, when it actually tries to use what it tried to load with the `include`.

If you don't actually need what the `include` statements are loading, then remove them from your code.

Comment: ok, thanks, seems legit. it seems that just the line `require_once("blub.php")` makes the error. after deleting it everything works fine. do you know something about my PS-question?

Comment: Does that file exist at that exact location?  What do you get from `ls -l /var/www/html/`?

Comment: yes, it does. your command displays `-rwxr-xr-x  1 ec2-user   ec2-user 6228  9. Jun 18:00 index.html` (and the other files and folder)

Comment: That error is timestamped as 5 minutes before the file's modify timestamp - the file probably did not exist at the time the error occured.

Comment: ok. i've looked up into the error_log file again... i think you're right because it now don't complains that the index.html is missing, but now every 3 (!) seconds an entry is made with /var/www/html/merlin-check is missing?!

Comment: Something's making a request for that file, which apparently doesn't exist.  Look at your access log if you need to determine what client's doing it to figure out why.  Maybe it's a resource loaded from your index file?

Comment: `10.224.55.160 - - [09/Jun/2012:18:31:37 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 6228 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
10.224.55.160 - - [09/Jun/2012:18:31:38 +0000] "GET /merlin-check/check.jsp HTTP/1.1" 404 302 "-" "-"` ... every 30 seconds the GET index.html, and after that every 3 seconds the merlin-check... don't really know what that should mean..

Comment: ahhh, i think that comes from the amazon elastic load balancer, could that be right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Is the same IP making the request to the merlin-check resource?

Comment: yes its the same ip. thank you for the help. the file does not exist (as error_log complains) but, yeah, whatever.